# populate drop-down values dynamically using Ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf, richfaces

I have 3 drop-downs. 1st drop-down contains some values when the page loads.
I need to populate 2 nd drop-down based on the value selected in 1st dropdown.
Similarly, I need to populate 3 nd drop-down based on the value selected in 1st and 2nd dropdown.

Initially I tried like this.

```
 <h:selectOneMenu value="#{stu.country}" >
  <f:selectItems value="#{bean.allCountries}" />
  <a4j:support event="onchange"  action="#{bean.retrieveStates(stu.country)}"  
  reRender="states_dropDown"></a4j:support>
   </h:selectOneMenu>
```

//ly, for 2nd drop-down

```
    <h:selectOneMenu id="states_dropDown" value="#{stu.state}" >
      <f:selectItems value="#{bean.allStates}" />
    <a4j:support event="onchange"  
     action="#{bean.retrieveCities(stu.country,stu.state)}"  
     reRender="City_dropDown"></a4j:support>
       </h:selectOneMenu>
```

Some times this code works fine. But some times it doesn't invoke managed bean method.

Can you please help??

Comment: did you resolve your problem? Give some feedback.

Comment: http://www.javatutorials.co.in/jsf-2-2-ajax-dynamic-drop-menu-list-example/ I think this Can Solve Your Problem .

Answer (score 1):

The first that comes to my mind is that you should declare the `<a4j:support>` with `immediate="true"`, so that no validation errors stop the bean from being called

Also, I'm having this one (it is inside a `<rich:comboBox>` though):

```
<a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="target"
    limitToList="true" eventsQueue="targetOnchange"
    action="#{bean.action}" ajaxSingle="true"
    requestDelay="500" />

<a4j:support event="onselect" reRender="target" limitToList="true"
    action="#{bean.action}" ajaxSingle="true" />
```

And it works fine. I've used the 2 events, because with `rich:comboBox` they mean different things. Actually, I'd suggest using the comboBox in your case, it will be more user-friendly.